# Prove that $f_n=-1+\prod_{i=1}^{n}(X-i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n=-1+\prod_{i=1}^{n}(X-i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $f_n$ is not irreducible, then there exists two polynomials $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$ such that $f_n(x)=p(x)q(x)$ with $\deg(p)<n$ and $\deg(q)<n$ hence for every $1\leq i \leq n$ we have:
$$-1=p(i)q(i)\quad p(i),q(i)\in \mathbb Z$$
from this we have for every $1\leq i \leq n$ $$p(i)=-q(i) $$
and this implies that $p=-q$ (two polynomials of degree less than $n$ which coincide in $n$ points) and hence:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(x-i)=-(p(x)^2-1) $$

This is not possible by comparing the leading terms.